# WriteLineAsync Error

Tags: c#, linq, async-await

I have this code that I am trying to use to convert a JSON object into a CSV file:

```
 private async Task WriteListrackClient (SyncConfig settings, ISyncMonitor monitor)
   {
       ICollection<OrderComposite> orders = null;
       string jsonOrders = File.ReadAllText(settings.productJsonConfig.FullJSONOrderFilePath);
       orders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ICollection<OrderComposite>>(jsonOrders);
       using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(settings.listrakProductFeed.ListrakCustomersFileLocation))
       {
           await writer.WriteLineAsync((orders.Select(x => string.Join(",",x.Customer.EmailAddress.ToString(), x.OrderId.Value.ToString(), x.DateCreated.Value.ToString(), x.TotalSalePrice.Value.ToString(), x.TotalSaleTax.Value.ToString(),0,0,"","","","",x.TotalDiscount.Value.ToString(),"online"))));
       };
   }
```

I am getting two errors I need some help with.  The first is on the writer.WriteLineAsync method.  It is: The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.TextWriter.WRiteLineAsync(char[]) has some invalid arguments.

The second is on the orders.Select statement: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable 'to 'char[]'

It seems to me the second error is a result of the first.  I am trying to use LINQ to pull in values as you can see.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The second argument for `string.Join` is an array of strings. [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk0xe5h0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Break up the monolithic line into separate lines and see if that doesn't better indicate where the problem is.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's kind of hard to see with the current formatting, but I think that at least part of your issue is that you're not doing a ".ToArray()" after your ".Select()"

Comment: In any case, it would be `.ToArray()` since the overload expects `char[]` and not `List<char>`

Comment: I added the .ToArray().ToString() to the end and it is now working.  Thank you.